# i get an error when i run script browser based install in importing data to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, .htaccess

I have an error in installing script it is browser based install I do the first steps right and write the database details also right but when the script try to import data to database I get this error:

```
Error running query : "CREATE TABLE `quizes` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`topic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ...". SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 1214 The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes 
(SQL: 
CREATE TABLE `quizes` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`topic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `image` varchar(255) 
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
NOT NULL, `pageContent` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `type` 
varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `questions` text COLLATE 
utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `results` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`ogImages` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `attempts` int(11) NOT 
NULL, `completions` int(11) NOT NULL, `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 
'0', `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `settings` 
text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `category` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `quizes_created_at_index` (`created_at`), KEY 
`quizes_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`), KEY `quizes_topic_index` 
(`topic`), KEY `quizes_attempts_index` (`attempts`), KEY 
`quizes_completions_index` (`completions`), KEY `quizes_active_index` 
(`active`), FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`topic`,`description`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; )
```

and here is the script htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

the website is in the root directory so can any one tell me the solution

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` script and seperate the error

Comment: actually i am not a developer and i am new here i can post the script download link if you like

Comment: So you want us to help solve a problem that normally a paid person would, for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be your DB doesn't support Full text indexes.

Try using

> ENGINE=MyISAM

instead of

> ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: thanks man it worked

Answer (score -1):

I think The problem is in your database driver you used now. your db driver doesn't support to create specific indexes, as you can see there is an error while creating a FULLTEXT indexes.

Comment: but the script previews version  worked just fine with me and i only add the update files and tried to reinstall the script then the error happened